Heapsort Implementation Using a Min-Heap (Ternary Heap) — Feedback on Correctness and Optimization
I’m working on implementing a heapsort algorithm using a min-heap, specifically a ternary heap, where each node can have up to three children. I know that my solution is inefficient, and I'm looking for feedback on whether my implementation is correct, as well as suggestions for optimizing it.
Problem Statement:

In our course, we discussed a binary heap. Analogously, a ternary heap
can be implemented, where each node has up to three children. The
children of the node at position i are located at the positions 3i +
1, 3i + 2, and 3*i + 3 in the array. The task is to implement
heapsort using such a ternary heap, ensuring that the algorithm works
in-place.
Implement heapsort using a ternary heap. Your algorithm should work
in-place. You should extend the HeapTernary class from Moodle. The
main method should not be altered, but helper methods can be added.
What is the worst-case runtime in O-notation for your algorithm?
Justify your answer.

My Solution:
Here’s my code implementation:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

class HeapTernary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random(42);
        int[] a = new int[17];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            a[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

        heapsort(a);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void heapsort(int[] a) {

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i * 3 + 1; j < i * 3 + 4; j++) {
                if (j < a.length) {
                    if (a[j] < a[i]) {
                        switchPos(a, i, j);
                        heapsort(a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void switchPos(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
}

I iterated through the entire array, comparing each node with its children. If a child node was smaller than its parent, I performed a swap to switch their positions. After the swap, I used recursion to verify whether the new parent node was smaller than its updated parent. This recursive check ensures that the min-heap property is maintained throughout the heap structure.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

That's an odd way to do a heapsort. Does it actually work? Your recursive algorithm will blow the stack if given a sufficiently large (less than 100 thousand) heap.
It would help if you showed us the HeapTernary code mentioned. Do you have a link to that? Otherwise we really can't comment on any modifications you make to it.
Typically, the heapsort works by repeatedly swapping the root of the heap (the smallest element in this case) with the last node in the heap, decreasing the heap size by 1, and then sifting the item down from the root. That is:
while n > 0
    smallest = extractMin(a)
    // extractMin reduced n, so we can put the previously-smallest
    // element where the old one was.
    a[n] = smallest

extractMin() removes the smallest item from the heap and re-arranges things so you still have a valid heap. It also decreases the size of the heap by 1. The second statement puts the previously smallest item (the one you just removed) at the end of the heap.
What you end up with, because you started with a min-heap, is an array that's sorted in descending order. If you want to sort in ascending order, you either need to start with a max-heap, or you need to reverse the array that resulted from working with a min-heap.
Note that the heapsort implementation isn't at all dependent on whether the heap is binary, ternary, quaternary, etc.

Thanks for your effort and help appreciate it ! I looked up the solutions and how it is supposed to be and forgot about my way of doing it.
